# how can I stream a response from a language model to Google Chat?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, google-chat

i implemented a Chat Bot using a http-endpoint like described here https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/gcf-app

With this, you can return a message as response:

```
res.send({
  text: 'Hi user!',
})
```

Many language models can stream their response. Is this possible to stream this response to the user as it arrives with google chat?